# Can python implement program-level virtual memory?

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, operating-system, out-of-memory

Recently, I wrote a python program, which requires a lot of memory. Then the computer memory is not enough, and it explodes.

It is known that the operating system will use part of the hard disk as virtual memory,which could solve the problem of insufficient memory. If you change the virtual memory of the operating system, you can solve the problem of insufficient memory in python programs, but the scope of impact is too wide.

Can python implement program-level virtual memory? That is, when the memory is insufficient, the hard disk is mapped to the program memory.

I need to run python program with large memory consumption.

Answer (score -1):

Using disk space as memory is usually called swapping.

It is usually simpler to do it yourself than making a script to do it for you. But if you insist on your script doing it for you, then a way is just to execute the commands you would use to do it manually.

Here is a tutorial for how to add swap to a Linux system (first result on google) : https://linuxize.com/post/create-a-linux-swap-file/

Take each command in that tutorial, run them using [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), and you will get the desired result.

If you are on Windows (which you did not tell) then the method applies (but I could not find quickly an easy way to do it with commands).

Comment: So does that increase the swap just for that subprocess, or what do you mean?

Comment: The swap is a system-wide characteristic. I don't think there is application-specific swap on usual operating systems.

Comment: But they already know about system-wide and the question is explicitly about *not* doing that.

Comment: Thus the question is unclear to me. Either they want their Python to have a specific swap file (which is not possible, to my knowledge), either they want their script to do it for them.